# Why doesn't the paint-on texture show when rendered (packed and saved texture)?

Tags: rendering, texturing

I'm both new to this website and Blender.

The problem is the painted on texture won't show when rendered as an image or animation. I have saved the texture and packed all of the files together but it still won't work. Is it something to do with the mapping? Please help. Blend file included

(texture included separately just in case)

Thanks 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your question and provide more information. What render engine are you using? How did you create your materials? Please include images that show your settings. The fastest way to get an accurate answer is by sharing your blend file.

Comment: I'm using the Blender render, and I think it's the newest version. How do I edit my question, and upload my folder? Thank you for replying though :) I think it might be something wrong with the textures.. I don't know

Comment: To modify your question use the **edit** option right under the "tags". To share your file use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and add the provided link to the text of your question.

Comment: Assuming you are refering to the character, I think you need to asign the texture in its material. Just look at the gun's material/texture setup and compare.

Answer (score 1):

The materials for the object don't have a texture associated with them.
Select your object.
In the materials slot select the material slot that will use the texture.
Move to the texture section and create a new texture that uses your image.[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was able to go off your advice from earlier and mirror the setup of the gun texture. I was afraid it would be something as simple as this, so thank you for taking your to help me with this ^_^